# Pyspark Dataframe to Sparse Matrix

Tags: pyspark

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.linalg.SparseMatrix.html#

I've read the documentation guide for how to creating a sparse matrix, but I don't quite understand how each parameter is supposed to be.

| index | userID | itemID | rating | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 196 | 242 | 3.0 | 881250949 |
| 1 | 186 | 302 | 3.0 | 891717742 |
| 2 | 22 | 377 | 1.0 | 878887116 |
| 3 | 244 | 51 | 2.0 | 880606923 |
| 4 | 166 | 346 | 1.0 | 886397596 |

Let's say I have a dataframe like this and want to convert it into sparse matrix in pyspark, what should the parameters be for this ?

to be exact, I want to understand what 'colPtrs, rowIndices, values' are supposed to be.

An additional question for experienced pyspark users, this sparse matrix is supposed to return csc format, but is there an built in function that allows csc sparse matrix to csr format ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [FeatureHasher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.feature.FeatureHasher.html) to transform feature columns to Sparse Vectors.